# Searching for array elements nested in MongoDB Documents

Tags: performance, mongodb

I need to store card documents in my database. Cards need to be stored with a set of integers that represent the bundle, box and pallet, or whatever other entity they belong to. The packaging structure needs to be of an arbitrary length to accommodate flexible packing structures (otherwise they would each have their own field in the document.)

I am considering a document structure like this, where the packaging numbers are kept as an array in the `Packaging` field.

```
{
"JobNumber" : "50001-01",
"CustomerId" : "joe",
"IdentifierNumber" : NumberLong(8812739),
"TimesPrinted" : 0,
"Packaging" : [ 
    1200, 
    120, 
    3
]
}
```

The Packaging field will be set once, then searched against many times.

I am wondering about performance because I will often need to query this collection for all documents whose nth element in the Packaging field is a given value. Is this something that MongoDB is good at? What are the indexes I should be considering?

Comment: This sounds like it is suited to some type of relational database management system, such as SQL Server.  What is the driving factor behind choosing MongoDB?

Comment: Good point. Scalability is my primary reason for going with MongoDB. Also, I don't mind the ease of setup and the C# driver support.

Comment: How much scalability are we talking about?  What is the average size of the documents you are attempting to store?  How many documents do you predict you might need to store per month, year, or over the lifetime of the product?

Comment: @MaxVernon also ... writes are unimportant to this workload, apparently

Comment: I ask this since SQL Server is totally capable of massive scalability, is extremely easy to setup, and has native C# support.  Plus, SQL Server allows real ACID compliance, whereas MongoDB does not offer any sort of ACID compliance.  See http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-db/transactions/acid.html

Comment: See this article for why you may NEED an ACID-compliant DBMS:  http://hackingdistributed.com/2014/04/06/another-one-bites-the-dust-flexcoin/

Comment: @MaxVernon - Documents are going to generally look like the one in the example. I'm anticipating 1-3 million records per month. I'm thinking tops we will keep 50 million docs at peak.

Comment: Please don't cross-post; choose the most appropriate Stack Exchange site and post it there.  If you later decide you need the question moved, simply "flag" it and ask a moderator to move it to the site you need.

Comment: @MaxVernon - Great article about ACID. I've been reflecting on it, and it seems like the fault is more in the user than the tool doesn't it? A banking application with transfer operations is the canonical example of why you need ACID. That someone would use a tool that is admittedly light on ACID for this application is unbelievable and speaks more to the developers than the database. Seems like MongoDB makes no attempt to hide its ACID position, since it is not a relational database to begin with.

Comment: @MaxVernon: While it is true that MongoDB does not offer ACID in a classical sense, it is absolutely possible to deal with the given use case. And nothing keeps you from saving a document like `{"transactionId":"12345","amount":500, date: ISODate("2014-09-26T18:21:00+02:00"),"remiteeAccount": "987654321","payeeAccount":"3234242"}`, which is how inter bank transactions are handled, for example (simplified here). Regarding massive scalability of SQLServer: Yes, it can be scaled, but has a huge overhead when compared to other systems, beginning with the OS. This adds up to whole machines, easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, MongoDB has a dynamic schema. So it is perfectly ok to store this document:

```
{
  "JobNumber" : "50001-01",
  "CustomerId" : "joe",
  "IdentifierNumber" : NumberLong(8812739),
  "TimesPrinted" : 0,
  "Packaging" : {"bundle":1200,"box":120,"pallet":3}
}
```

and this document

```
{
  "JobNumber" : "50001-02",
  "CustomerId" : "jane",
  "IdentifierNumber" : NumberLong(8812739),
  "TimesPrinted" : 0,
  "Packaging" : {"sack":200}
}
```

in the same collection.

Since, I wouldn't query for the Nth document, but for a given field in the subdocument, for example

```
 db.collection.find({"packaging.bundle":1200})
```

which would run just fine with MongoDB. The reason behind that is that if a field isn't present in a document, it is evaluated as `null` for a query. And `null` is definitely not equal to 1200.

As for the performance. It really depends on who big your collection is and how your queries look like. While the query as shown above may be rather slow in a collection containing hundred of thousands of documents (or even more) without an index, it can be extremely fast when you created an index on it, e.g.

```
    db.collection.ensureIndex({"packaging.bundle":1,"packaging.box":1,"packaging.pallet":1});
```

If you can create an index like this obviously depends on the question wether you really have arbitrary packaging or if you simply have a variety of packaging options. If the latter is the case, I'd create an index for each of the packaging options, utilizing [sparse indices](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/), e.g.

```
 db.collection.ensureIndex({"packaging.sack":1},{sparse:true})
```

This would reduce the index size, as only documents which hold the field "packaging.sack" would be contained in this index.

If you really have arbitrary fields in the documents, I wonder how you create a model for it ;)

When talking of just some ten thousands of documents, you might even get satisfying result without an index.